# How to make an employee wage restriction?

Tags: sql, database, numeric

I have a database with an employee table. This table has the attributes:
name, id, adress and salary.

I need to restrict the salary of employees between US $ 5000 to US $ 10,000. How can I implement this restriction?

My attempt was to define the data type of the salary attribute as:

```
      NUMERIC (5000, 10000)
```

However when I went to search the sql documentation I saw that NUMERIC (p, s) means
p: precision
s: scale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [`check`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) constraint when you create the table:

```sql
salary NUMERIC 
CONSTRAINT salary_range
    CHECK(salary >= 5000 and salary <= 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Check constraint while creating the table.

create table (
name,
id,
adress,
salary check (salary between ( 5000 and 10,000))